# How to perform a query via bootstrap search box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In the form_tags I can easily add methods and get params from the text_field_tag, for example to query a database or to perform a search.

FORM_TAG

```
</form>
          <%= form_tag usernotes_path, method: 'get' do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], size: 150, placeholder: "Search", class: "searchInput"%>
          <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

Now I am trying to use bootstrap "search" form, but not sure how to achieve the same result as the form_tag (where to put the method, how to add actions, how to perform a query?)

BootStrap Search

```
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
  <%= form_tag usernotes_path, method: 'get', class: 'navbar-form', role: 'search' do %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], size: 150, placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-default") do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This should be it, didn't tested it in an app but I think it will work, let me know in a comment if it's not.

Comment: Thanks. Functionality works but the object positions not quite. Search Box appearing at the top then below the search box are btn-success and glyphicon-search. I fixed the positioning now